# Server can't ping, curl or openssl paypal.com or api.paypal.com

Tags: ubuntu, server, paypal

When running any of the above commands: `openssl s_client -connect api.paypal.com:443`, `curl https://api.paypal.com` or `ping api.paypal.com`. I always get the same response of a etimeout.
Example:

> curl api.paypal.com
> curl: (28) Failed to connect to api.paypal.com port 80 after 130579 ms: Connection timed out

I tried updating the system and updating the ca-certificates.
I tried changing the DNS resolve to 8.8.8.8 and disable the ufw firewall

I ran traceroute on paypal.com and got this return:

> traceroute to 64.4.250.36 (64.4.250.36), 30 hops max, 60 byte packets
> 1  _gateway (172.31.1.1)  4.943 ms  4.826 ms  4.807 ms
> 2  24156.your-cloud.host (65.108.118.147)  1.031 ms  1.080 ms  1.067 ms
> 3  * * *
> 4  * * *
> 5  core32.hel1.hetzner.com (88.198.249.93)  1.546 ms core31.hel1.hetzner.com (88.198.249.89)  1.526 ms core32.hel1.hetzner.com (88.198.249.93)  1.511 ms
> 6  core53.sto.hetzner.com (213.239.254.62)  7.752 ms core52.sto.hetzner.com (213.239.254.58)  7.119 ms  7.070 ms
> 7  core3.sto.hetzner.com (213.239.252.66)  7.056 ms core3.sto.hetzner.com (213.239.252.74)  6.836 ms core3.sto.hetzner.com (213.239.252.66)  6.794 ms
> 8  netnod-ix-ge-b-sth-4470.f5.com (195.69.119.96)  10.016 ms netnod-ix-ge-a-sth-1500.f5.com (194.68.123.96)  23.177 ms netnod-ix-ge-b-sth-1500.f5.com (194.68.128.96)  23.142 ms
> 9  * * *
> 10  * * *
> 11  * * *
> 12  * * *
> 13  * * *

**FOR ANYONE INTERESTED**
The solution was to change from api.paypal.com to api-m.paypal.com. Because api-m is a better cdn and should be used when using paypal rest api. [more here](https://github.com/woocommerce/woocommerce-paypal-payments/issues/1480)

Comment: This is probably a network routing issue... Are you behind a proxy or in a private network? It does seem like the DNS resolution worked (you can test the DNS resolution using `dig` or `nslookup`), but the tcp request never actually made it to the address. Since `api.paypal.com` has virtually open ingress, I would image you have some sort of egress rule (IE a in a firewall) blocking your outgoing request.

Comment: use `curl -v`, and also something like `dig` to get an IP followed by `traceroute`

Comment: Good idea to use `traceroute` like Preston recommended after you've tested the DNS resolution with `dig` or `nslookup`.

Comment: @ThisGuyCantEven no i am not behind a proxy using dig and nslookup the ip resolved correctly but i can't figure out wht is blocking it. I tried it on a diffrent server i own and it worked.

Comment: Use the `traceroute` like Preston recommended to try and see where in the network the tcp request is breaking down. (`traceroute $IP_FROM_NSLOOKUP`)

Comment: That node you're stuck on is an f5 node owned by an ISP in Sweden. Unfortunately, I do not get routed through this node when I try to use their API, but it's possible they are rejecting UDP/TCP traffic from certain sources.

Comment: @ThisGuyCantEven Solved

Comment: It looks like they came to a similar conclusion to my initial thought, which is that your cloud provider has some sort of firewall/blackhole in their networks preventing the egress.